# VBAでPCのセッションIDを取得したい

Tags: windows, vba, session

Excel VBAで、コマンドプロンプトから `query session` で取得できるセッション番号をコードで拾えるようにしたいのですが、どうすればできますでしょうか。

他のサイトを見て、Shellを使用して取得しようとしたのですが、戻ってきた値は空でした。

テストとして書いてみただけのコードですので、どうして `i` が文字列変数なのかとかは気にしないでください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

下記がそのコードです。

```
Dim wsh As Object

Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'コマンド結果を格納する変数
Dim result As Object
Set result = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 
Dim cmd As String
Dim filedata() As String
Dim i As String
 
'実行したいコマンド
cmd = "query session"
 
'コマンドを実行
Set result = wsh.exec("%ComSpec% /c " & cmd)
'コマンドの実行が終わるまで待機
Do While result.Status = 0
    DoEvents
Loop

'結果を改行区切りで配列へ格納
filedata = Split(result.StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
 
'A1から順番に結果を書き込む
i = ""
Dim filenm As Variant
For Each filenm In filedata
    i = i & filenm & vbNewLine
Next
 
Set result = Nothing
Set wsh = Nothing

MsgBox i
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 試した方法は VBA で直接セッションIDを取得しているわけではありませんよね？コマンドプロンプトでの実行の段階でNGなのか、VBAで結果を加工する過程で問題が出ているのか…などの切り分けが必要じゃないでしょうか。

Comment: Windows10とMicrosoft365 Excelでブック・シートを作っただけで何もデータ等が無い状態で質問のソースをマクロとして入力・実行を試したところでは、セッション情報は取れているようでメッセージボックスで表示されました。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。掲載したコードを丸写ししても正しく結果が得られたということでしょうか。私の方はresultに値が入っていません。その時の画像を追加しました。

Comment: はい、そうです。掲載されたコードをそのまま`Sub QuerySession()`と`End Sub`の間に挿入コピーして関数を実行したら、最後の`MsgBox i`の時点で`query session`の内容がメッセージボックスで表示されました。追記された画面の`i = ""`の時点では、`result`と`filedata`の両方にデータが入っています。

Comment: 私が使用しているPCでは画像の通り、何も取得できていません。端末の問題なのでしょうか。試しにほかのPCで試したところ、確かに取得できました。一度質問を閉じて再度内容を変えて質問しなおした方が良いでしょうか。

Comment: 質問を閉じるのではなく、PCによって取得出来たり出来なかったりする状況を追記して、その原因を探る質問に変えてみるというのも手では？ あとはそれぞれのPCで @cubick さんのコメントのように作業を段階的に分けて状況を探って、それも追記してみるとか？

Comment: sayuriさん回答の`C:\Windows\Sysnative\query.exe`は64bitコマンドプロンプトでは動作しなかったのでこの辺の記事を参考にVBA側で実行環境を判定してプログラムパス名を切り替える必要があるでしょう[【VBA】ExcelやOSのバージョンを取得する](https://jizilog.com/vba-versionget), [Office の 32 ビット バージョンと 64 ビット バージョン間の互換性](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/client-developer/shared/compatibility-between-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office), [VBA 32Bit版と64Bit版でDeclareステートメントの宣言を分ける方法 - Office 2010,2013](https://www.saka-en.com/office/vba-32bit-64bit-declare-statement-branch/), [Excel VBA インストールされているExcelが64bitか32bitかを返す関数 ExcelIs64bit](https://qiita.com/Q11Q/items/c189544333af84e07f65)

Comment: ありがとうございます。乾燥でいうと、コマンドプロンプトからではとても一筋縄ではいかなさそうな感じですので、コマンドプロンプト経由ではなく、直接セッションIDを取得できるAPIなどの方法はないでしょうか。もしあるようでしたら、ご教授いただければと思います。ない場合は、これまでいただいた方法で実装してみます。

Comment: APIとしてはローカルPCで使えるか分かりませんが、[WTSQuerySessionInformation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationw)とか[WTSEnumerateSessions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumeratesessionsw)でしょうか？ ただそれを使えても情報を得るのは大変そうなので、VBAで判断できそうなこちらの記事とかの方が良さそうです。[【ワレコの講座】VBAをEXCEL2007,2010,2013,2016,2019の32/64 bit全対応させるには？【解決】](https://www.wareko.jp/blog/how-can-i-make-vba-correspond-to-all-32-or-64-bit-of-excel-2007-2010-2013-2016-2019)

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にしてみます。

Answer (score 1):

`query.exe`は64bit版の`C:\Windows\System32\query.exe`は存在しますが、32bit版の`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\query.exe`は存在しません。
その上で、32bitプロセスが`C:\Windows\System32`を参照しようとすると[File System Redirector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)の機能により`C:\Windows\SysWOW64`にリダイレクトされてしまいます。

そのため、32bit版Excelから外部プロセスとして`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\System32\query.exe`を起動しようとすると（リダイレクトされて`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\System32\query.exe`が実行されます。32bit版cmd.exeは`C:\Windows\System32\query.exe`を実行しようとしますがリダイレクトされて）`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\query.exe`を実行しようとして「コマンドが見つからない」となります。

解決策は、同ページに説明があるように（Windows Vista以降であれば）`C:\Windows\Sysnative`を使用することです。`C:\Windows\Sysnative`を指定すると32bitプロセスであっても`C:\Windows\System32`を参照できます。

今回であれば実行ファイルとして`C:\Windows\Sysnative\query.exe`を指定してください。

Answer (score -3):

こちらの環境でも同じ現象が発生しますが、次のようにコードを変更したところ`query session`の結果を取得できるようになりました。

【変更前】

```
'実行したいコマンド
cmd = "query session"
```

【変更後】

```
'実行したいコマンド
cmd = "C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-t..es-commandlinetools_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_9aa166e99861c2bc\query.exe session"
```

環境によってquery.exeのパスは変わるかもしれません。問題が解消しない場合はquery.exeを検索し、見つかったパスで試してみてください。

【実行結果】
[image: 実行結果]

【確認に使用した環境】

```
エディション  Windows 10 Pro
バージョン   20H2
OS ビルド  19042.1237
エクスペリエンス    Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0
```

---

query.exeが完全パス名ではないのが原因と考え、query.exeを検索してみました。
`C:\Windows\System32\query.exe`が見つかったので、こちらで実行したところ現象はかわりませんでした。※セッションの情報が取得できない
`C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-t..es-commandlinetools_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_9aa166e99861c2bc\query.exe`も見つかったので試しに実行してみたところ現象は解消しました。

この２つのquery.exeのサイズ、タイムスタンプは同じでした。
どうしてこの２つのquery.exeの振る舞いが変わるのかは不明のままですが、単にqueryとした場合は`C:\Windows\System32\query.exe`が起動され、セッションの情報が取得できないのだと思います。

---

見つかったquery.exeと実行時のふるまいは次のとおりです。

```
C:\Windows\System32\query.exe session
```

- cmdから実行可能
- VBAから実行しても値が返らない

---

```
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-t..es-commandlinetools_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_9aa166e99861c2bc\query.exe session
```

- cmdから実行可能
- VBAから実行すると値が返る

---

```
C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-t..es-commandlinetools_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_a4f6113bccc284b7\query.exe session
```

- cmdから実行できない。
- 以下のダイアログとメッセージが表示される。

[image: ダイアログの画像]

```
このバージョンの C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-t..es-commandlinetools_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_a4f6113bccc284b7\query.exe は、実行中の Windows のバージョンと互換性がありません。コンピューターのシステム情報を確認してか ら、ソフトウェアの発行元に問い合わせてください。
```